# Is there an adjective meaning "chicken-like"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word 'birdlike' means 'resembling a bird,' and 'ornithoid' is a more scientific-sounding word for the same thing. Is there a word with a similar meaning that's specific to chickens? There's 'chicken-like,' but I'm wondering if there's a better option.

Comment: Are you using the adjective to describe something that is not a bird (like a person or a thing)?

Comment: _Chicken-like_ (or _chickenlike_) is an adjective already, specific to chickens. Why does it not work? How do you want to use the word?

Comment: @ermanen chickenlike is understandable, and if communication were the sole purpose of the word choice, it would do just fine.
But, in this case, I was looking for variety.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Galliformes** /ˌɡælɪˈfɔːrmiːz/ is an order of heavy-bodied ground-feeding birds that includes turkeys, **chickens**, quail, and other landfowl. Gallinaceous birds, as they are called, are important in their ecosystems as seed dispersers and predators, and are often reared by humans for their meat and eggs, or hunted as game birds.[...] The name galliformes derives from "gallus", Latin for "rooster". Common names are gamefowl or gamebirds, landfowl, gallinaceous birds, or galliforms.
>
> [Wikipedia: Galliformes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galliformes)

Comment: The adjective is "**galliform**" or - MW "**gallinaceous** adjective: of or relating to an order (Galliformes) of heavy-bodied largely terrestrial birds including the pheasants, turkeys, grouse, and the common domestic chicken. -- *This gallinaceous volume — possibly his 32nd, who can keep count? — includes a gallery of his paintings of chickens, anecdotes from his remarkable life and recipes that are more story than instruction.* Karen Heller, Washington Post, 1 Oct. 2022

Answer (score 1):

If you want something less formal and more easy to understand than gallinaceous etc, there is **chickeny**, which isn't in most dictionaries but is in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chickeny) "resembling a chicken or its meat" and [Your Dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/chickeny) likewise.

It is used by corporations e.g. grocery chain [Kroger](https://www.kroger.com/r/chickeny-seitan-recipe/135079) speaks of "chickeny seitan" (having the flavor of chicken) and a British vegan pie company, [Clive's](https://groceries.asda.com/product/the-pie-shop/clives-organic-chickeny-puff-pie/1000376529224), does the same. There's also a [children's book](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/the-chickeny-chicken-quinn-burrough/1141986151) called *The Chickeny Chicken* by Adrienne Genthe.